# Django Channels doesn't detect WebSocket request with NGINX

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, channel, daphne

I am deploying a website on AWS. Everything works fine for HTTP and HTTPS. I am passing all requests to Daphne. However, incoming WebSocket connections are treated as HTTP requests by Django. I am guessing there is some header that isn't set in Nginx, but I have copied a lot of my Nginx config from tutorials.
Nginx Config:

```
upstream django {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}


server {
        listen 80;

        server_name 18.130.130.126;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name 18.130.130.126;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/private.key;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;


        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://django;
        }
}
```

Daphne is bonded to 0.0.0.0:9000. Channels have a very basic setup. A ProtocolTypeRouter, with AuthMiddlewareStack and then URLRouter, as shown on the Channels tutorial. And then a Consumer class. I am using Redis for the channel layer, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. This is some data about the request on response from fiddler. The request headers say Upgrade to WebSocket, but it returns a 404 HTTP request, as it doesn't see it as a WebSocket request.[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

include proxy params was the problem. It was overwriting headers.